# OpenCV - Yolo - count detected object in specific area

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, devicehive

I'm using this repo for some test as I'm quite new to OpenCV:
https://github.com/devicehive/devicehive-video-analysis

My goal is to count how many detected object as "Person" are confined into specific area on the video.

So I'm trying to playing with the code here:

```
for o in predictions:
                x1 = o['box']['left']
                x2 = o['box']['right']

                y1 = o['box']['top']
                y2 = o['box']['bottom']

                color = o['color']
                class_name = o['class_name']
                # Draw box
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 60)
                all_objects.append((o, class_name))
                # Draw label
                (test_width, text_height), baseline = cv2.getTextSize(
                    class_name, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, 1)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1),
                              (x1+test_width, y1-text_height-baseline),
                              color, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(frame, class_name, (x1, y1-baseline),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 0, 0), 1)
                # People Count
                if class_name == 'person':
                    test += 1
```

But i'm really unable to figure it out when prediction occour, how can I calculate object area and detect if it's inside another one pre-defined.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you
S

Comment: you could use intersection of masks or intersection of rectangles or testing whether center of gravity is inside some area or probably much more different approaches. Depends on your definition of "in specific area" which isnt trivial.

Comment: Do you know where I can try to pick up pieces of code to test it? Intersection of rectangles is enought for me. thx

Comment: in C++, openCV uses cv::Rect and provides intersection and union with && and || operators, maybe there's something similar for python api.